# Module over an infinite dimensional algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, modules

I have two question related to infinite dimensional algebra

1. I have been seen a lot of example about Module over a finite dimensional $k-$algebra, but I could not find a literature  about Module over an infinite dimensional $k-$algebra, so why this?
2. I need a reference in which the theory of infinite dimensional algebra have been discuss there in detail or even partially.

Comment: The thing is : the fact that a ring is an algebra over some field $k$ does not give that much information if the dimension is not finite (of course it is still something, but nowhere near as good as the finite-dimensional case). So usually people either deal with finite-dimensional algebras to really benefit from the special situation, or with general rings to get a fully general theory. That's why there is not much litterature on the case you're looking for (I'm not saying there's nothing, but clearly nothing as rich as the finite-dimensional case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Infinite-dimensional algebras" is, perhaps, too broad.

However, if what you are looking for is families of infinite-dimensional algebras for which the representation theory has been described/studied, I would suggest having a look at Section IV.3 of Pierre Gabriel's *Des catégories abéliennes* (available from [NUMDAM](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/BSMF/BSMF_1962__90_/BSMF_1962__90__323_0/BSMF_1962__90__323_0.pdf)).

In this paper, topological modules over some topological rings (called *pseudo-compact rings*) are studied.  Any finite-dimensional algebra over a field is pseudo-compact; so is any formal power series algebra.  Some highlights of the theory:

- Any pseudo-compact ring is a direct *product* of projective pseudo-compact modules.
- The category of pseudo-compact modules over a pseudo-compact ring is abelian, has cogenerators and exact projective limits.